# How to disable the namespace auto import in Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: visual-studio

Since I have installed Visual Studio 2015, one thing really bother me...

When you override a method or implement an interface using the automatic intellisense way... it import all the "required" namespace as "using" on the top of the file.

As we have the coding rule to use "fully qualified" name in our company, I have then to go on the top of the file, clean all the using, then go to the method and add all the namespace "correctly".
It take me "a lot of time" to do that every time...

[EDIT] Even when I use the quick action stuff![/EDIT]

Regardless of the "usefulness" of "fully qualified", do anyone of you know how to disable this?
I searched for using and namespace in the option but didn't found anything.

I know Resharper can do it... but we do not have licences for now, so the question is: can VS do it?

Thanks for reading!
flo.

Comment: Just for the record... I didn't found a solution. So I did grab a Resharper licence and it work like a charm... 
If anyone find another workaround, just let me know ^^

Answer (score 0):

After typing the partial name into Visual Studio will underlined it in red and possibly show a "light bulb" symbol. The context menu for the red-underlined name should include "Quick actions" (or "Resolve" on older versions). The options then offered include "using ..." and the full name of the item. Select the full name

For example. When I type `Regex rex;` into a C# method, the `Regex` is underlined in red. If I select the `using ...` action then a `using System.Text.RegularExpressions` is added to the top of the file. If I select the other action my code is changed to `System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex rex;`

Comment: Thanks for your answer! 
Well, I do know about quick action stuff. What I wanted to point out is when I override a method, it automatically import the using. I certainly can delete the using and use the quick action to fully qualify my method, but it would be more efficient to just not import the using and directly fully qualify my method...